# Eclipse - Installed PyDev and nothing changed

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

This isn't my first time using Eclipse or installing PyDev but this is the first time it both succeeded and failed.

It succeeded because it installed, it shows up as being installed and installation went on fine without a problem.

It failed because nothing has shown up, there is no Python perspective, no PyDev views in the view list, no new projects under PyDev, no PyDev preferences. It is as if it is not actually installed at all.

The only thing I did differently is extract the latest eclipse to a folder called ~/eclipse and create a short cut to run it there (the latest Eclipse), usually I use `apt-get` to install eclipse, realise it's an old version (C++11 stuff missing) then upgrade and do this. Somehow PyDev is usually carried forward.

I'm not sure how it can list it as being installed but have this error, I'd appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it's the problem of 3.x version of PyDev. It demands java 7.

2 solutions are possible:

- Install java 7. re-run the Eclipse, Pydev should function well now. OR
- Install last 2.x version of PyDev.

  To do it

  1) Remove PyDev : In Eclipse About window click Installation Details
  button below. You will see controls for removing plug-ins.

  2) Install 2.x version of PyDev:

  - Eclipse Help->Install New Software.
  - REMOVE CHECKBOX "Show only the latest version" located at the bottom of the dialog.
  - Choose Pydev update site from the list and in the appeared list of PyDev versions choose latest in 2.x branch.

Comment: It worked, but before I tick I'd like to ask about the java 7 option, I installed openjdk-7.* (everything with a 7) and still no luck, but I didn't try reinstalling PyDev after, should I reinstall to test this, also checkboxes not radiobuttons governed what versions I could install, can I install multiple versions, if so how does switching work? (while I love eclipse, evidently there are many menus I have yet to explore :P)

Comment: Ok. Multiple versions of plug-in - neither tried nor imagine how to switch. Sorry. Java7 - you should tell Eclipse which java to use OR remove other java packages from the system OR define java7 as default java. To check the currently used java version in Eclipse see About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration tab. Line starting with: java.runtime.version=...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really that sometimes even installing java 7, Eclipse does not get it.

In http://pydev.org/download.html, there's a section called: PyDev does not appear after install!

Try to follow it to see if it fixes your problem (i.e.: making Eclipse find java 7).

Another option would be using PyDev standalone (i.e.: LiClipse). Although it's commercial, it should come with all the requisites builtin (so, no hassles to install) and is updated whenever PyDev itself is updated.